Xampp Php Informix jdbc
I need help to get result from informix server through xampp.
I installed Xampp 3.3.0 on windows 11.
I used
$conn= osbc_connect (DSN, username, password);
and also used
$dbo = new pdo (odbc:dsnname,username, password)
to connect sucessfully with our informix server.
It's very slow and showing result very late.
On otherhand I am also using razorsql and connect informix via jdbc driver. It's processing queries very fast and showing result quickly.
Now my question is

Is there any connection string for jdbc and how (i didn't install Jdk but installed jre)
Is there any other connection method for connecting informix server for fast result.

odbc connection worked
But I want jdbc or any other fast connection setting.

You can't use a JDBC driver with PHP.

ISTR that sometimes a dubious DNS setup could really slow down connections on the C-based APIs without affecting the JDBC performance.  I forget the details, and frankly, I've no idea where to look for them.  It was probably in the old emails from the email system we used two changes of email ago.
